# JDBC Sink connector using an existing function in a database

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using Confluent JDBC Sink Connector to propagate changes from a Kafka topic to a database.
I'd like to use an existing DB function to generate primary keys, but it seems the connector doesn't support it.

here is my connector config:

```
{
  "name": "bios-jdbc-sink-connector",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "connection.url": "*****jdbc:db2",
    "connection.user": "****",
    "connection.password": "****",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "sink_bios",
    "connection.ds.pool.size": 5,
    "insert.mode": "insert",
    "table.name.format": "TBATCH_TABLE",
    "pk.mode": "none",
    "transforms": "rename,generate_pk",
    "transforms.rename.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Value",
    "transforms.rename.renames": "GF:GF#,ABH_GF:ABH_GF#,FK:FK#",
    "transforms.generate_pk.type" : "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value",
    "transforms.generate_pk.static.field" : "PK#",
    "transforms.generate_pk.static.value" : "{call CREUUID(1)}"
  }
}
```

I've tried to call `CREUUID(1)` function, - as it's possible with JDBC API wia `prepareCall` - but it doesn't work with the connector.

Do I need to implement a custom transformation for this functionality, or did I miss a configuration option for the primary key?

I appreciate any insights or suggestions. Thank you!